# Show that this is the correct decision rule on a likelihood ratio test

Tags: statistics

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $X_1 ... X_n$ be a random sample from the following PDF:

$$\frac{\theta}{x^{\theta+1}}, x \ge 1, \theta \ge 0 $$

If

$$p = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$$
$$H_0: \theta = 1$$
$$H_a: \theta \ne 1$$

Then show (or disprove) that the decision rule given by a likelihood ratio test is to reject $H_0$ if

$$\log(p) - n\log\log(p) \gt k  $$ 
for some constant k.

The numerator in the likelihood ratio is

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i^2} = \left[\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^nX_i}\right]^2 = p^{-2}$$

while the denominator is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$. To calculate the MLE I did:

$$l(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\theta) - (\theta + 1)\log(X_i)$$

Differentiating and setting to zero, I get

$$\frac n \theta - \sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i) = 0 $$

and the MLE is

$$n\left[\sum_{i=1}^nlog(X_i)\right]^{-1} = n\log(p)^{-1} $$

So the likelihood ratio test becomes

$$\frac{p^{-2}}{n\log(p)^{-1}} \lt k $$

Then,

$$-2\log(p) + \log\log(p) - \log(n) \lt k \text{    (k absorbs log)}$$
$$2\log(p) - \log\log(p) + log(n) \gt k$$

...and that's the farthest I can get. Is the job done or did I miss a step?

Comment: From what I understand, you define the likelihood ratio as $L=\frac{f(\{x_i\}|\theta=1)}{\max_\theta f(\{x_i\}|\theta)} = \frac{f(\{x_i\}|\theta=1}{f(\{x_i\}|\theta =\hat{\theta}_\textrm{ML})}$. However, you seem to compute $\frac{f(\{x_i\}|\theta=1)}{\hat{\theta}_\textrm{ML}}$ instead.

Comment: Of course! I got it now thanks :)